# All the built in notification tones are now gone after clearing the Media Storage app's data

Tags: notifications, 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia, ringtone

The Album app on my phone fails to detect some of the pictures I have after I moved them. I tried clearing the Album app's data but it didn't do anything. After looking around the internet, I found that one way to refresh media apps is to find the Media Storage system app on the Settings and then clear it's data. After I did that, I noticed my notifications on some messaging apps stopped having sound. When I tried to select a new notification tone for it, I found out that all the default ringtones and notification sounds are missing. Is there a way to get this resolved like maybe there's a directory where these tones are placed in the system, or am I SOL?

EDIT:
After digging around, I found my notifications, ringtones, and alarm sounds are still in `/system/media/audio/` but for some reason the ringtone selection dialog doesn't detect them. They don't have a `.nomedia` on the folder so it can't be that. Is there a way to force them to be rediscovered?

Comment: Restart device,  wait for a few minutes for the database to be indexed again

Comment: I could've sworn I've restarted multiple times to no avail, but I'm probably having false memories. I'm restarting now to see if it does the trick. Will update.

Comment: Also see if clearing cache helps

Comment: Back after 30 minutes, still nothing. I've rebooted the phone already. What app should I clear the cache to?

Comment: Tough luck. Clearing cache is the same way as you cleared data.  Long pressing on *Storage* of that app should show both options

Comment: Yeah it's not working at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I can't remember why but I know I cleared my media storage when trying to fix something. Of course, the guide I was blindly following never mentioned that it would silence my alarms as a byproduct

Using the search `"Media Storage" android tones gone`, I found some good resources that led me to the [ScanMediaPlease](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.scanmediaplz&gl=US) app, which forces the process to reindex the stuff. The app worked where rebooting failed for me.

#### Resources

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.scanmediaplz&gl=US
- https://github.com/zhuowei/scanmediaplz
- https://androidforums.com/threads/lost-ringtones-after-deleting-media-storage-data.712580/
- https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/644611-repopulating-media-after-clearing-media-storage.html